CSS: Why won't my dropdown display change when checkbox is :checked?
I'm trying to set .hamburg-nav to display: block; using a checkbox with :checked.
If I hard-code .hamburg-nav as display:block then it appears perfectly.
If I click the checkbox, nothing appears to be happening.
I've read that its possibly because of the hierarchy and I can not target outside of the element? I'm not really understanding.
<div class="header-right-container">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              class="hamburg-checkbox"
              id="hamburg-toggle"
            />
            <label for="hamburg-toggle" class="hamburg-toggle">
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </label>
          </div>
        <nav class="hamburg-nav">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

input:checked ~ .hamburg-nav {
  display: block;
}

.hamburg-nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

.hamburg-toggle {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 6px;
  display: none;
}

I've tried using numerous different selectors and changing classes and ids around.

~ is a sibling selector and the input is not a sibling of the nav.

@Paulie_D is correct, if you were to remove the div wrapping the input & label elements, they would be siblings and this would work
